# Push Wizard App not found error

Tags: php, push-notification

I need to implement [Pushwizard](https://pushwizard.com/) in PHP to send push notification.

I have implemented this php code

```
$api_key = "MY_API_KEY";
$msg = "Website PHP msg.";
$data = array("command" => "send", "message" => $msg);
$data_string = json_encode($data);
$ch = curl_init('https://pushwizard.com/api/'.$api_key.'/json');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ( 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print $result;
```

But it gives me this error message.

```
{"error":"0002","error_msg":"app not found"}
```

I have check my configuration. From pushWizard admin panel I can able to send push notification, It works fine there. But from PHP api it is giving me an error.

I have googled it but not able to find any answer.
Does any own implemented it??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to use the API with the App Key instead of the API Key.
[image]